# PySpark Dataframe transformation for coordinate data

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe in PySpark, where each entry is a location for a journey with "constant"  values Id, Start and Stop, and varying coordinates.

| Id | Lat | Lon | Start | Stop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40.5 | 40 | A | B |
| 1 | 41.0 | 45 | A | B |
| 1 | 40.5 | 40 | A | B |
| 2 | 31.4 | 59 | A | C |
| 2 | 34.5 | 60 | A | C |
| 2 | 37.0 | 61 | A | C |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

I want to transform this dataframe into

| Id | Start | Stop | Trajectory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | Vector of Coordinates |
| 2 | A | C | Vector of Coordinates |
| ... |  |  |  |

My first thought was to iterate through each row in the dataframe, create a "trip object" for each new Id with Id, Start and Stop and a trajectory list, and then append the lat and lon as a Coordinate object to the trajectory list, however since the dataset is enormous, this would probably computationally expensive.

I have never used Spark before, so there are probably some smart tricks one could use to make it very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not sure what exactly do you need on output but check this code as a started for improvements or discussion. For sure you can chcange columns which are used in groupBy, add ordering or the way how points are created (i am just adding lat and long separated by :)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

inputData = [
    ("1", "40.5", "40", "A", "B"),
    ("1", "41.0", "45", "A", "B"),
    ("1", "40.5", "40", "A", "B"),
    ("2", "31.4", "59", "A", "C"),
    ("2", "34.5", "60", "A", "C"),
    ("2", "37.0", "61", "A", "C"),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(inputData, schema=["id", "Lat", "Lon", "Start", "Stop"])

aggregatedDf = (
    df.withColumn("Point", F.concat_ws(':', F.col("Lat"), F.col("Lon")))
    .groupBy("id", "Start", "Stop")
    .agg(F.collect_list("Point").alias('Trajectory'))
)

aggregatedDf.show(truncate = False)
```

sample output:

```
+---+-----+----+---------------------------+
|id |Start|Stop|Trajectory                 |
+---+-----+----+---------------------------+
|1  |A    |B   |[40.5:40, 41.0:45, 40.5:40]|
|2  |A    |C   |[31.4:59, 34.5:60, 37.0:61]|
+---+-----+----+---------------------------+
```